# Opening file in existing process by PID

Tags: c#, .net, process

Is there a way to open a file in an existing process (instance of an application) instead of creating a new instance every time `Process.Start()` is used?

For example:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    Arguments = @"C:\Temp\Test.txt",
    FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\...\devenv.exe"
};
Process.Start(psi);
```

This will create a new instance of Visual Studio every time the code is executed. Is it possible to capture the PID of the Visual Studio process the first time it is started and open any new files in that existing instance?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about Visual Studio, or any program?

Comment: @RonBeyer Any program that supports opening multiple documents but I need this for VS and Dreamweaver specifically...

Comment: For Visual Studio, you need to add an argument `Arguments = @"C:\Temp\Test.txt /Edit"` which will open it in an existing instance. This is entirely based on the application if it supports it. You can't really pass arguments to a PID. I'm not sure if Dreamweaver supports that.

Comment: What if there are multiple instances of VS running? How to open in a specific instance? Or will /Edit just open it in the last instance used?

Comment: You can't, I'm not sure how Visual Studio picks the instance to open it in.

Comment: Gotcha, hard to believe this can't be done... that you can't open a file in a specific instance of an application by providing a PID.

Comment: @DeanKuga: Is it hard to believe that an application can be written that doesn't open a file in an existing instance?  If you can believe that, then surely you can believe that there is no universal method of forcing an application to open a file on command, in an instance of your choice.  If you don't believe that, explain just why you expect `int main() { puts("Hello World"); }` to magically start opening files on request.

Comment: @RonBeyer: For Visual Studio specifically, the problem could be solved by writing an extension.  Each instance that loads the extension just creates a unique mailbox, when a filename is dumped into the mailbox the extension calls the VS function to open a file.  In no way does this help with the general case.

Comment: Just to confirm that /Edit switch works for VS and it will launch an instance if there are no instances running. If two or more instances are running it will open it in the instance first launched even if the PID is higher than the other instance(s) and other instance is focused.

Comment: @BenVoigt Okay, okay, off with my head...

Comment: @DeanKuga: It wasn't a bad idea, but as a software developer you should be thinking about what logic your app would have to have to make it possible, and whether OS libraries could take care of that logic for you.  Then you would have reached the conclusion that document handling is too different between applications -- some don't have documents, others access them over the network, others store them inside databases, in addition to the "usual" method of file-based storage -- that no universal solution is possible.

Comment: @BenVoigt It's not about my app's logic it's about the host app logic. If an app provides MDI interface or opening multiple documents in general I would expect it to provide the arguments or API to accomplish that task programmatically. For example, Beyond Compare provides a way via arguments to open two files to compare I would expect the same from any application that supports editing multiple files.